# Why does my stored proceedure return null along with required data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I use the below stored proceedure to populate data in my report table, along with the required data it returns several null populated rows

stored proceedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `logdb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Dummy_2`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`logdb`@`10.%` PROCEDURE `Dummy_2`(
    IN      log_table      VARCHAR(50)
)
BEGIN   

SET @sqlstring = CONCAT("INSERT INTO report(ID, name, accountname, accountID, status, imprcount, earliest_imp,recent_imp)
SELECT  DISTINCT b.ID, name, accountname, c.accountID, status, total_impr, min(a.timestamp), max(a.timestamp)
FROM    ",log_table," a INNER JOIN logs b on a.ID = b.ID INNER JOIN accounts c on b.accountID = c.accountID

WHERE   a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR);");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstring;
    EXECUTE stmt;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

screenshot data

[image]

can anybody help me to avoid these null rows

Comment: most likely those fields are null in the other tables, so when you select them over, those nulls come across too. check the corresponding source records, and you'll find that some other fields in those records aren't null.

Answer (score 0):

Add another statement in `where` clause 
`WHERE a.timestamp > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AND b.ID <> null`